# How are flags used in linux for file protection?

Tags: permissions, directory

I am unsure about the term flags used in Linux as I have recently heard of them, whilst doing educational research. And from what I am aware of 'flags' is they are used within directory's to show the access permissions for a particular file. So my real question is, how are they used? where can I see them myself? and tell me if im missing something obvious then tell me, as I thinking this maybe the case.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Do you mean the permissions described here?: http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Answer (score 1):

The only time i've come across the word 'flag' in a context even remotely related to file protection was was 'read flag' and 'write flag'. That was just a fancy way of saying 'permissions'. As in 'clipboard.sh has no 'read flag' and 'PERswitch.pl' has an 'excute flag':

```
confus@confus:~/bin$ ll
-rw-------  1 root   root    1863 2011-05-13 00:23 clipboard.pl
-rwxr--r--  1 confus confus  3331 2011-05-06 01:46 PERswitch.pl*
```

So could be, that you missing something that obvious. But I don't think thats it. That would be just babytown frolics.